# Как находить этимологию слов,без использования платных книг?

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

Очень хочется для себя искать этимологию из проверенных источника,бесплатно.Какими сайтами пользоваться и как проверять информацию?

Comment: Несколько этимологических словарей есть на этом сайте: https://dic.academic.ru/

Comment: Спасибо,а есть ещё какие-то?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/pampas . Даль, Ушаков, Ожегов и далее по списку в порядке убывания полезности или в зависимости от слова, например технические термины лучше смотреть в технических словарях само собой, но на Академике их много разных, если приспособиться. Шарон любит словарь Кузнецова ещё. + НКРЯ - https://ruscorpora.ru/ , Картуслов можно, когда она не перепост педивикии. Педивикия в крайних случаях, очень осторожно.

Comment: Шарон любит только Черных)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В поиск отправляете: "Этимологические словари онлайн".

Получаете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этимологический словарь русского языка Семенова](https://rus-etmo-semenov-dict.slovaronline.com/)

Я предпочитаю Шанского:

[Этимологический онлайн-словарь русского языка Шанского Н. М.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/shansky/)